# Basic conditional probability ques

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Say from a bag of fruits with 50% apples and 50% oranges, we sample 2 images with replacement. What is the probability of getting an apple and an orange? Why should it not be 0.25?

My understanding is that these 2 are independent events given we are doing the replacement. So 0.5 for apple and 0.5 for orange and we take the product to get 0.25.

No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two cases:

- Case 1: we get an apple first, then an orange (with probability $0.5\times 0.5=0.25$)
- Case 2: we get an orange first, then an apple (with probability $0.5\times 0.5=0.25$)

This gives a total probability of $0.25+0.25=0.5$.